# Columns with 1 pixel height

Tags: css, sass, gumby-framework

I am using the [Gumby framework](http://gumbyframework.com/docs/) grid and am having a problem with the columns. I have the following code:

```
<div class="row appointment-container"> 
    <div class="columns one">
        <img class="appt-calendar" src="appt.png">
    </div>

    <div class="columns eight">
        <div id="last-appointment">
            <h4 class="confirm-appointment next-block">
                <span class="appt-text">Lorem ipsum intellectus testus integer string float test test test</span>
            </h4>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="columns three">
    </div>
</div>
```

With the following SCSS:

```
.appointment-container {

  position: relative;

  .appt-calendar {
    max-height: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    margin: auto;
  }
}
```

The "columns eight" and "columns three" display correctly but the "columns one" has a height of only one pixel despite having content in it. What would cause this to happen?

Comment: Does Gumby use floats for its columns? Does your `img` have any style on it? Add `display: block` to the `img` and see if that fixes it. If not, try floating it.

Comment: I believe Gumby uses tables. display:block did not work. I will edit my question to include the CSS I have.

Comment: The syntax of your css is incorrect... (*unless you're using SASS or something that i'm not familiar with*)

Comment: Then you need to specify a width for the image. also please tag it in question.

Comment: @Jonfor does setting a width for the image work..?

Comment: @Tilwin I found the issue. See my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that

> position:absolute

on the image caused the column to collapse to 1 pixel. I do not know if this is something only Gumby has or if other frameworks have the same framework but I will update this answer once I find out.

Comment: That's why i said you need to set the width explicitly -_-